# How to add slaves to local mode? How to setup Spark cluster on Windows 7?

Tags: apache-spark

I am able to run the apache spark on windows with `spark-shell --master local[2]`. How we can add slaves to the master node?

I think YARN and Mesos are not available on Windows. What are the steps to setup the Spark cluster on Windows 7?

Switching to Unix based system is not option available to us as of now.

Comment: what about [Spark Standalone](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the relevant link to setup spark cluster on Windows.

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-start-master-and-workers-on-Windows-td12669.html

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** You cannot add slaves to `local` mode.

`local` mode is the only non-cluster mode where all Spark services run within a single JVM. Read [Master URLs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) for the other options (regarding the master URLs).

If you want to have a clustered deployment environment you should use Spark Standalone, Hadoop YARN or Apache Mesos as described in [Cluster Mode Overview](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html). I highly recommend using Spark Standalone first before going into a more advanced cluster managers.

I'm on Mac OS, so I can be sure the cluster managers work on Windows 7 reliably, but I did see Spark Standalone working on Windows. You should use `spark-class` to start the Master and slaves as the startup scripts are for Unix OSes.